# Keep a particular element in view, even when its previous siblings are growing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page where the content of various elements are AJAXed in to a core structure. The structure itself is pretty simple, and the elements don't have any special positioning on them:

```
<body>
    <article id="one"></article>
    <article id="two"></article>
    <article id="three"></article>
</body>
```

The contents of each article is loaded via AJAX calls, and the length of the content for each is not knowable ahead of time. Additionally, each section can be navigated to with URLs (so I can get to `#two` with `mysite.com/two`; it loads the page and scrolls down to the requested article).

This works great, of course, after all of the content is loaded, but my trouble is when the content before the target element has not loaded yet. Because the elements have to expand to fit the content, it pushes down the target element, so instead of getting this:

```
____________________
| Target Element   |
|                  |
|__________________|
| Next Element     |
|__________________|
```

you get this:

```
_____________________
| Previous Element  |
|                   |
|                   |
|___________________|
| Target Element    |
|___________________|
```

I've tried setting a minimum height for the content blocks, but that only works part of the time, and only really works if the final height is close to the original height.

Ideally, I'd like the viewport to stay in the same position relative to the content even if the user has scrolled before all of the content has loaded in, but I'll settle for it keeping the position before the user tries to scroll.

Is there any way to do either of these?

Comment: How are you converting the URL param to a hash? Can you delay that a bit?

Comment: @isherwood - It's a quick string replace, but no, I can't delay it. Half the point is to load at a given section as though it were its own page.

Comment: Ok. What about an ajax callback that moves back to the hash?

Comment: @isherwood - If flickers occasionally, but that seems to work. Add your comment as an answer, and if it holds up to some further testing, I'll be sure to mark it. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

1. Get the height of any previous element before the ajax call to load. Save it.
2. After if finishes loading, on ajax call completed successfully, get the new height.
3. Calculate how much bigger it is using the difference.
4. Scroll the page up that amount.

If the element is after the current one, don't scroll.

*Aside*

This is one of my pet peeves with some web pages. They load and you start reading. Then a 2 inch tall add slides in and moves what you are reading off the page. Or worse yet, you scroll down and start reading and for no apparent reason the text just slides off the bottom of the page because an unseen add just loaded itself up above.

Comment: Re the aside - Yeah, I sympathize. It's not my design, though, and I'm in no position to make such decisions on this project. =/

Answer (score 0):

Created a small demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/dS5tq/

Check this out.

Try to scroll down to second div after page load.

I used `setTimeout` to add more text and cloning existing paragraph for text.

**HTML Code**

```
<div>
    <div id='one' class='box'>
        <p>um vulputate pretium id nec lorem. Cras ut pharetra massa. Aliquam venenatis ipsum pellentesque lorem viverra eleifend. Pellentesque in<p>
    </div>
    <div id='two' class='box'>
        <p>ger elementum, orci eu tincidunt vehicula, nisl felis semper odio, lacinia elementum risus leo vitae dui. Fusce dictum, justo a consequat ullamcorp<p>
    </div>
    <div id='three' class='box'>
        <p>ce in cursus leo. Integer lorem urna, lacinia mollis libero aliquam, consequat luctus lacus. Mauris pulvinar consequat justo, sed mattis sapien<p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
* { padding : 0; 
    margin : 0; 
}
.box {
    font-family : Arial;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color : #eee;
    padding : 10px 10px 0 10px;
    line-height : 24px;
    margin : 10px;
}
p {
    margin-bottom : 10px;
}
#two {
    background-color : #ece;
}
#three {
    background-color : #eec;
}
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        addContent($('#one p:last').clone(), $('#one'));
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        addContent($('#one p:last').clone(), $('#three'));
    }, 5000);
});

function addContent(data, tgt) {
    var current_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var tgt_pos = $(tgt).offset().top;

    if(tgt_pos < current_pos) {
        var currentHeight = $(tgt).height();
        $(tgt).append(data);
        var newHeight = $(tgt).height();
        $(window).scrollTop(current_pos + newHeight - currentHeight);
    } else {
        $(tgt).append(data);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set the target to absolute positioning and put it at the top of the screen scroll to it which is essentially scrolling to top and then put an on-first-scroll event on the window object that reset the target element. http://jsfiddle.net/DjBHX/

```
// get the target element
var target = $("#two");
// set it to absolute position
// now its at the top no matter what
target.css("position", "absolute");
target.css("top", 0);
// scroll to the top of the page / target
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
// fake loading
$("article").each(function() {
    // load $(this).load(blah);
    var elm = $(this)
    var spam = this.id; 
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
        spam += spam + "<br>";
    elm.html(spam);
});
// first scroll set target back to static positioning
(function() {
    var fnFirstScroll = function () {
        // remove the event
        $(window).off("scroll", fnFirstScroll);
        // reset the target article
        target.css("position", "static");
        target.css("top", "auto");
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.scrollTo(0, target.offset().top);
        }, 10);
    }
    $(window).on("scroll", fnFirstScroll);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at doing an ajax success function:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function() {
    // simulate link click or somesuch
  }
});
```